# How to get table hover bootstrap 4 to start working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I created a table that is filled with items from an array and I wanted to add table-hover to it but it's not working. Any suggestion for how I can make it work?

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Log Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let log of logs">
        <td>{{log.text}}</td>
        <td class="log-date"> {{log.date | date: 'short'}} <i (click)="onDelete(log)" typle="button"  class="close">&times;</i></td>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code should be working fine, check if you have added the CDNs for Bootstrap4 correctly, also I think you missed to add `<tr>` tag for table data in `<tbody>`to be aligned correctly. If this does not work please show the complete code to check.

Comment: @BineeshJohn adding the `<tr>` tag worked. It was so simple, i spent so much time trying to figure it out. Thank!

Comment: That's great it worked, I will have this added in answer please mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Since you missed to add table row tag there was no row created in the first place to show hover functionality.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Log Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let log of logs">
        <tr>
            <td>{{log.text}}</td>
            <td class="log-date"> {{log.date | date: 'short'}} <i (click)="onDelete(log)" typle="button"  class="close">&times;</i></td>
        <tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```